# Is there a difference in the derivative services between forge and Bim 360?

Tags: autodesk-forge

IFC file generated from Revit seems to lose certain objects (particularly Rebars) when translated through Forge Model Derivative API. The same file looks OK on BIM 360.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the switch loader option to use the Revit based IFC loader. This option is true by default on BIM360 e.g.

```
curl -X 'POST'
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'
     -H 'Authorization: Bearer PtnrvrtSRpWwUi3407QhgvqdUVKL'
     -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job'
     -d
      '{
         "input": {
           "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bW9kZWxkZXJpdmF0aXZlL21vZGVsLmlmYw",
         },
         "output": {
           "formats": [
             {
               "type": "svf",
               "views": [
                 "3d"
               ],
               "advanced": {
                 "switchLoader": true
               }
             }
           ]
         }
       }'
```

ref: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/model-derivative-ifc-pipeline-call-change

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found it in the API documentation too. But the blog post gives a better view on the reason behind the option. It seems to work alright now. Many thanks.